# CMake Link error 1 using ExternalProject_Add

Tags: c++, git, cmake, mingw, external-project

I recently switched the build system of my C++ project to CMake. I am trying to use the ExternalProject_Add function to download the required libraries(there are currently 3 of them, GLM and TINYOBJ are static and GLFW can be either static or dynamic) using git then link to them in my project. I want to be able to link these libraries (and possibly others) with minimal effort so that I can build on multiple platforms. Or if someone else comes in to work on the project, they won't have to worry too much about getting the correct libraries installed.

However, I keep getting these errors when building (on Windows 10 with MinGW):

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable app\OpenGLTest.exe
CMakeFiles\OpenGLTest.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `FPSCounter::getElapsedTime()'
CMakeFiles\OpenGLTest.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `FPSCounter::reset()'
CMakeFiles\OpenGLTest.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `FPSCounter::setLastTick()'
CMakeFiles\OpenGLTest.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `FPSCounter::addFrame()'
CMakeFiles\OpenGLTest.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x12d): undefined reference to `GLCamera::getCameraZoom()'
CMakeFiles\OpenGLTest.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x149): undefined reference to `GLCamera::setCameraZoom(float)'
CMakeFiles\OpenGLTest.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x1de): undefined reference to `GLCamera::getCameraPosition()'
CMakeFiles\OpenGLTest.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x747): undefined reference to `GLCamera::setCameraTarget(glm::tvec3<float, (glm::precision)0>)'
CMakeFiles\OpenGLTest.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x771): undefined reference to `GLCamera::setCameraPosition(glm::tvec3<float, (glm::precision)0>)'
CMakeFiles\OpenGLTest.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x968): undefined reference to `GLRenderer_Deferred::GLRenderer_Deferred()'
CMakeFiles\OpenGLTest.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0xb98): undefined reference to `FPSCounter::FPSCounter()'
CMakeFiles\OpenGLTest.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0xba2): undefined reference to `FPSCounter::FPSCounter()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\OpenGLTest.dir\build.make:98: recipe for target 'app/OpenGLTest.exe' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [app/OpenGLTest.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/OpenGLTest.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/OpenGLTest.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My directory structure looks like this:

```
|-Project
  |-BUILD (all the CMake output files are here)
  | |-app (this is where the .exe is output to)
  | |-downloads (dependencies are downloaded here)
  |   |-deps
  |-OpenGL (this is the source directory)
    |-deps-CMakeLists.txt
    |-CMakeLists.txt
    |-src
      |-Main.cpp
      |-**Other source files and headers of the "undefined reference" errors are in this directory**
      |-RenderSystem
        |-More Source files
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(OpenGLTest)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/app)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(EX_PROJ_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/downloads/deps/Source)
set(EX_PROJ_BUILD_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/downloads/deps/Build)

# Include OpenGL
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
if (OPENGL_FOUND)
    include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()

# Include GLEW
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
if (GLEW_FOUND)
    include_directories(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

set(GLFW_LIB_DIR ${EX_PROJ_BUILD_DIR}/GLFW_EX/src)
link_directories(${GLFW_LIB_DIR})

# Download and unpack gtest at configure time
configure_file(deps-CMakeLists.txt downloads/CMakeLists.txt)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" . WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/downloads)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/downloads)

# Add gtest directly to our build
add_subdirectory(${EX_PROJ_SOURCE_DIR}/GLM_EX
                 ${EX_PROJ_BUILD_DIR}/GLM_EX
                 EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL )
add_subdirectory(${EX_PROJ_SOURCE_DIR}/GLFW_EX
                 ${EX_PROJ_BUILD_DIR}/GLFW_EX
                 EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL )
add_subdirectory(${EX_PROJ_SOURCE_DIR}/TINYOBJ_EX
                 ${EX_PROJ_BUILD_DIR}/TINYOBJ_EX
                 EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL )

# Add the gtest include directory, since gtest
# doesn't add that dependency to its gtest target
include_directories(${EX_PROJ_SOURCE_DIR}/GLM_EX/glm
                    ${EX_PROJ_SOURCE_DIR}/GLFW_EX/include
                    ${EX_PROJ_SOURCE_DIR}/TINYOBJ)

# add the executable
add_executable(OpenGLTest src/Main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(OpenGLTest tinyobjloader glm glfw3 ${GLEW_LIBRARIES} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})

add_custom_command(TARGET OpenGLTest POST_BUILD        # Adds a post-build event to MyTest
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different     # which executes "cmake - E copy_if_different..."
        "${GLFW_LIB_DIR}/glfw3.dll"                   # <--this is in-file
        $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:OpenGLTest>)                 # <--this is out-file path
```

This is the deps-CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(deps-download LANGUAGES NONE)

include(ExternalProject)
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES EP_BASE "./deps")

# Include GLFW
ExternalProject_Add (
       GLFW_EX
       GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/glfw/glfw.git"
       GIT_TAG "master"
       CMAKE_ARGS -DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF
                  -DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS=OFF
                  -DGLFW_BUILD_DOCS=OFF
                  -DGLFW_INSTALL=OFF
                  -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON
       UPDATE_COMMAND    ""
       INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
       TEST_COMMAND      "")

# Include GLM
ExternalProject_Add (
       GLM_EX
       GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/g-truc/glm.git"
       GIT_TAG "master"
       UPDATE_COMMAND    ""
       BUILD_COMMAND     ""
       INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
       TEST_COMMAND      "")

# Include TINYOBJ
ExternalProject_Add (
       TINYOBJ_EX
       GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/syoyo/tinyobjloader.git"
       GIT_TAG "master"
       UPDATE_COMMAND    ""
       BUILD_COMMAND     ""
       INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
       TEST_COMMAND      "")

add_dependencies(GLFW_EX GLM_EX TINYOBJ_EX)
```

My "main" is located in Main.cpp in the "src" directory along with all the files referenced in the errors as "undefined reference". I've added the include directories for all the libraries(right after the ExternalProject_Add command) and attempted to link the dynamic library being built for GLFW but it still doesn't seem to work.

What am I missing to get this to build correctly? Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I've shuffled some things around and moved the `ExternalProject_Add` commands to another file which are executed during the configure phase of my build, as suggested by Craig Scott. I've made sure that all the external libraries are linked. I even tested each library separately in a different test project to make sure the CMake files work.

All of the "undefined references" I'm getting are from files that I wrote, and are in my source tree. How/Why are they not being included?

Note: I have also tried to include the "src" directory but doesn't seem to do much of anything.

Comment: You have only listed _src/Main.cpp_ in your `add_executable` command, so if all your undefined references are coming from things in _src_ and below, add the missing source files from in there to your `add_executable` command.

Comment: There are a lot of them and I plan to add a lot more. Is there a good way to add all of them? I thought CMake was supposed to take care of that.

Comment: No, you have to explicitly list them all. It's a one-time thing and makes explicit what you expect to be included in the target, so it's also good from a robustness point of view. Some people are tempted to use CMake's `file(GLOB...)` command, but even the CMake documentation itself discourages that as it doesn't properly handle when you add or remove source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I was having was caused by not adding the source files to the final executable. I fixed the issue by adding a `file(GLOB...` just before the `add_executable` command like this:

```
# get all *.cpp files recursively
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp)
# add the executable
add_executable(OpenGLTest ${SRC_FILES})
```

I will probably move to a solution that involves a more explicit way of adding source files in the future since `GLOB`s are not recommended.

Thanks to Craig Scott for your help.

Answer (score 1):

While your CMakeLists.txt file does build the external projects, your OpenGLTest target doesn't link to them. Presumably, they are what provide the missing symbols your linker is complaining about. Simply adding those external projects as dependencies won't also add them to your OpenGLTest target.

To fix this problem, you need to add the external libraries to your `target_link_libraries` command. Unfortunately, those libraries won't exist when you run CMake (well, not the first time anyway), so you have to manually work out the details of the libraries (but see further below for an alternative). It may be enough to know just the directory in which `ExternalProject` will put them. It should be predictable for every build, so you can work out what it is by looking at one of your test builds. I believe you can then just add that path to the linker search path and list the base name of the library in the `target_link_libraries` command (the base name meaning drop any leading "lib" on unix-like platforms as well as the file suffix). If that doesn't work, you will need to construct the full path to the library and add that to the `target_link_libraries` command instead. This would require more work, especially if you want to build on multiple platforms (the set of CMake variables CMAKE_..._LIBRARY_PREFIX and CMAKE_..._LIBRARY_SUFFIX may be helpful here).

If manually specifying the library details bothers you and if the external projects also use CMake, there is a way to get `ExternalProject` to download the sources for you but then use `add_subdirectory` to bring them directly into your project. They would then have CMake targets you could use to specify on your `target_link_libraries` command and would have the added benefit of always being built with consistent compiler/linker flags as the rest of your project. The technique is discussed with Google Test as the example here:

https://crascit.com/2015/07/25/cmake-gtest/

If you wanted to, you could modify that approach to do the whole build at CMake time and then use `find_library` or similar, but that would make the CMake step potentially very costly and is not normally recommended.

Comment: Does it make any difference if the libraries are static or dynamic? GLM and TINYOBJ are both static libraries while GLFW is a dynamic library(and already added to the target_link_libraries command). I've tried adding GLM and TINYOBJ to the command be then CMake yells at me.

Comment: It shouldn't matter other than changing the CMake variable you use to construct the library name (if you're using that approach). For example, static libraries would use CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX and CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX, whereas dynamic libraries would use CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX and CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX. In your question, you are not linking in GLM or TINYOBJ.

Comment: Perhaps update your question with GLM and TINYOBJ added to the target_link_libraries command and also update the CMAKE output so the resulting errors are shown.

Comment: I've updated my question. I also tried doing some of the things on the link you posted. I put all the externalproject_add calls in to another file and configured it using the main CMakeLists file. Now I get the error described in this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676277/cmake-target-include-directories-prints-an-error-when-i-try-to-add-the-source). I only get the error for GLM and GLFW but I think it's because they are being exported in their CMakeLists files

Comment: It still looks like you haven't updated your `target_link_libraries` command. Until you do that, your OpenGLTest executable won't be able to link.

To help with the error you get now as described in that other stack overflow question, try using `target_include_directories` and `target_link_directories` instead of  `include_directories` and `link_directories` throughout your CMakeLists.txt. You should then be able to use generator expressions to fix your problem as described in that other post.

Comment: I've updated my question with some of the stuff you suggested. It still doesn't want to link to my own files for some reason.