# CMake autogenerated export file for relocatable library

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, shared-libraries

I have a very simple library with a header file and a source file. I'm using CMake to compile it, initially like this:

```
add_library(libOEInfoProvider SHARED
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/OE/InfoProvider.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/OE/InfoProvider.cpp)

# see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25681179/276451
target_include_directories(libOEInfoProvider
    PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:dist/include>)
```

I've now configured it so that `make install` generates all necessary files in a `dist` folder, like so:

```
install(TARGETS libOEInfoProvider EXPORT libOEInfoProviderConfig
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/lib
)

install(DIRECTORY
    src/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/include)

install(EXPORT
    libOEInfoProviderConfig DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/cmake)

export(TARGETS libOEInfoProvider FILE libOEInfoProviderConfig.cmake)
```

The problem I have is that the geneerated `.cmake` files contain **absolute paths** to the `dist` folder, but I need to deploy this library somewhere else with a different directory structure. Therefore I'd need to have relative paths in the `.cmake`, so wherever I place the library, the moment I use `find_package` in the client code it should be able to find the code.