# why INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES error appears when adding FILE name. Cmake

Tags: cmake

how come cmake does not give an error when not specifying FILE name?
I understand that when FILE name not specified, cmake gives it the project's name...by this logic should be mandatory to specify path...

no error:

```
install(FILES 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/my_math/addition.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/my_math/division.h
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/my_math)

install(TARGETS my_math EXPORT my_export DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/my_math)
install(EXPORT my_export DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/my_math)
```

INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES error:

```
install(TARGETS my_math EXPORT my_export DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/my_math)
    install(EXPORT my_export 
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/my_math
        FILE my_math-config.cmake)
```

complete error message:

```
CMake Error in my_math/CMakeLists.txt:
  Target "my_math" INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property contains path:

    "/home/alon/cmake/sandbox/Install/my_math/include"

  which is prefixed in the source directory.


-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

Comment: <code>
CMake Error in my_math/CMakeLists.txt:
  Target "my_math" INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property contains path:

    "/home/alon/cmake/sandbox/Install/my_math/include"

  which is prefixed in the source directory.


-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
</code>

Comment: just did ! thanks for the tip

Comment: Ok, but what is your question? Do you want to know how to handle this error message? If so, then see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676277/cmake-target-include-directories-prints-an-error-when-i-try-to-add-the-source).

Comment: actually i am trying to understand why ,when cmake uses its default name (project), there is not error but only with custom export names

Comment: I would find strange that checking for `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property is performed only when `FILE` option is given to `install(EXPORT)` command. It smells like your tests (with `FILE` option and without it) have **something else** to be different. E.g. different build or install directories.

Comment: Note also, that while **export file** (`YYY.cmake`, created with `install(EXPORT)`) could be used as a **config file** (`XXXConfig.cmake` or `xxx-config.cmake`, consumed by `find_package()`), the most flexible usage is achieved when config file is created by different approach. See the tutorial about creating a package file in CMake [documention](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages).