# Installation issue with a `FetchContent`ed library

Tags: installation, cmake, fetchcontent

I am trying to install and export the target defined by the following `CMakeLists.txt` in a Windows environment. It uses `FetchContent` to download a library from github. I can build the library with no problem and generate `nfd.lib`. My goal is to use this library in my other projects.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(mynfd VERSION 1.0.0)
include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(nfd
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/btzy/nativefiledialog-extended.git
        GIT_TAG c++-version)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(nfd)
```

At this point, `nfd.lib` is successfully built in `_deps/nfd-build/src/nfd.lib`.

When I add the following install commands to the `CMakeLists.txt` above, I run into issues.

```
# Installation
include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS nfd
        EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets
        FILE_SET HEADERS
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${nfd_SOURCE_DIR}/src/include
        )

install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets
        FILE ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets.cmake
        NAMESPACE ${PROJECT_NAME}::
        DESTINATION lib/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME})
```

I get the following error messages.

```
CMake Error in cmake-build-debug-visual-studio/_deps/nfd-src/src/CMakeLists.txt:
  Target "nfd" INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property contains path:

    "C:/Dev/myproject/src/test/cmake-build-debug-visual-studio/_deps/nfd-src/src/include/"

  which is prefixed in the build directory.


CMake Error in cmake-build-debug-visual-studio/_deps/nfd-src/src/CMakeLists.txt:
  Target "nfd" INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property contains path:

    "C:/Dev/myproject/src/test/cmake-build-debug-visual-studio/_deps/nfd-src/src/include/"

  which is prefixed in the build directory.Target "nfd"
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property contains path:

    "C:/Dev/myproject/src/test/cmake-build-debug-visual-studio/_deps/nfd-src/src/include/"

  which is prefixed in the source directory.
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: It seems the project is not intended to be exported: it [uses](https://github.com/btzy/nativefiledialog-extended/blob/master/src/CMakeLists.txt#L63) `target_include_directories(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC include/)` without `$<BUILD_INTERFACE>` / `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE>` division.

Comment: Is it possible to override this in my `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: Well, you know which property and of which target is wrong. With [set_property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html) command you could write proper value to it. (Proper format of the property you could find in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676277/cmake-target-include-directories-prints-an-error-when-i-try-to-add-the-source))