# Unable to use FetchContent to add dependency target to project

Tags: c++, cmake, build, dependencies

I'm trying to use CMake's [FetchContent](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html) to automate dependency fetching when not found / unavailable locally, but I'm currently facing an issue when installing / exporting my project for 3rd-party use.

In particular, my project optionally requires [CvPlot](https://github.com/Profactor/cv-plot):

```
find_package(CvPlot QUIET)
if (${CvPlot_FOUND})
        message(STATUS "Found cv-plot [${CvPlot_VERSION}]")
else()
    message(STATUS "CvPlot not found, fetching...")
    FetchContent_Declare(CvPlot
            GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/Profactor/cv-plot
            GIT_TAG         master
            SOURCE_SUBDIR   CvPlot
    )
    FetchContent_MakeAvailable(CvPlot)
endif()

# ...

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC CvPlot)
```

which I then add to my export targets:

```
install(TARGETS CvPlot EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets)
```

but which results in multiple errors for each `CvPlot` header/source files.

```
Make Error in deps/cv-plot/CvPlot/CMakeLists.txt:
Target "CvPlot" INTERFACE_SOURCES property contains path:

 "/<project>/build/_deps/cvplot-src/CvPlot/inc/CvPlot/Internal/<header>.h"

which is prefixed in the source directory.
```

However, I've noticed that cloning the repository *outside* the project's directory and including it with `add_subdirectory` naturally results in a successful build, as the header/source files are no longer prefixed by the build directory; however, that is not the behavior I was looking for:

```
add_subdirectory(/some/other/path/cv-plot/CvPlot build/_deps/cv-plot-build)
# ...
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC CvPlot)
# ...
install(TARGETS CvPlot EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets)
```

From what I've gathered (in particular through [this insightful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25681179)) the issue may be related to how `target_sources` are defined in `CvPlot` CMake configuration; nevertheless the fact that including from (or installing to) an external directory outputs no error suggest there may be some other solution to the issue.

Comment: `add_subdirectory(/some/other/path/cv-plot/CvPlot build/_deps/cv-plot-build)` - In that invocation the directory `/some/other/path/cv-plot/CvPlot` is not treated as a **source** one of **your project**. So, while the headers inside that directory are INTERFACE ones, CMake doesn't blame for them. Still, the project setup is wrong: if after installing your project you will delete the directory `/some/other/path/cv-plot/CvPlot`, then your export file won't be working, as it contains paths to non-existent files.

Comment: So the solution would be to update the CMake setup of the dependency (which does not, for instance, differentiate between sources in install/build trees), or is there a way for me to circumvent this issue on my project?

Comment: When use `FetchContent_Declare`, you could specify PATCH_COMMAND for patch the sources of the other project. Alternatively, you may read property INTERFACE_SOURCES of `CvPlot` in your code, modify it (e.g. replace paths in the source tree with appropriate `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE>` and `$<BUILD_INTERFACE>` generator expressions) and write back to the property.