# CMake: transitive dependency for header only lib with fetch content

Tags: c++, cmake, build

My code is compose of multiple modules. One of them depends on the PCG lib. I get it through fetch content with the following:

```
FetchContent_Declare(
  pcg
  GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/imneme/pcg-cpp"
  GIT_TAG "v0.98.1")
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(pcg)
```

In the module directly depending on it I declare the lib include dir like so:

```
target_include_directories(${LIBRARY_NAME} PRIVATE ${pcg_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

and the module builds fine. But when I try to build a second module, depending on the first one (but not directly on PCG) I get a complaint that the headers can’t be found.

So I tried the following:

```
target_include_directories(${LIBRARY_NAME} INTERFACE ${pcg_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

but now I get the error that "INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property contains a path which is prefixed in the build directory".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if your target's header files depend on pcg you need to use `PUBLIC` rather than `PRIVATE` includes

Comment: 'I get the error that "INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property contains a path which is prefixed in the build directory' - Have you searched for that error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676277/cmake-target-include-directories-prints-an-error-when-i-try-to-add-the-source

Comment: PUBLIC, PRIVATE, INTERFACE visibility is quite ok summed up [in this blog post](https://leimao.github.io/blog/CMake-Public-Private-Interface/). Or [this quick answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64843062/4165552).

Comment: In your example I think the use of `FetchContent_Declare` is an overkill. That `pcg-cpp` library is header-only and consists of 3 files. Just download `v0.98.1` and simply embed it in your project, e.g. under `ROOT/3rdParty/pcg-cpp/include`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I tried `PUBLIC` instead of `INTERFACE` and get the same error. With `PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${pcg_SOURCE_DIR}/include>` as suggested (did I get this right?) the configuration step passes, but again on build the compiler complains that it can’t find the header file.

Comment: Please, provide more code ([mcve]) and the exact error message. Current description in the question post is very vague.